# How to create dict in the django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to get an JSON response from the API and give a response with the selected field. I have fetched the response but I am not able to create a response with the new value. I am very new to python world and in learning stage.

```
def search(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    searchQry = request.POST.get("searchQry","")
    nodeIP = settings.NODEIP
    params = {'search':searchQry}
    apiResponse = requests.get(url = nodeIP, params = params)
    data = apiResponse.json()
    newArray = {}
    nodeName = 'RPID'
    if nodeName == 'RPID':
        for x in data:
            newArray['cphNumber'] = x["data"]["cphNumber"]
            newArray['farmName'] = x['data']['farmName']
            newArray['addressLine1'] = x['data']['addressLine1']
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(newArray))
else:
    return HttpResponse('Unauthrozed Access')
```

My response array looks likes this :

> [{"data": {"cphNumber": "321","farmName": "313","addressLine1": "13","addressLine2": "13","region": "13", "postalCode": "13"},"id": "4c1b935664e6f684e89ee363f473ce3567599d4b9da0f5889565d5b6f0b84440"},{"data": {"cphNumber": "321","farmName": "313","addressLine1": "13","addressLine2": "13","region": "13","postalCode": "13"},"id": "7cbe7be9797896545410ed6c4dcc18064525037bc19fbe9272f9baabbb3216ec"},{"data": { "cphNumber": "321","farmName": "313","addressLine1": "13","addressLine2": "13","region": "13","postalCode": "13"},"id": "7df10c0b7b84434d5ace6811a1b2752a5e5bca13b691399ccac2a6ee79d17797"}]

In response I am getting only one array. I know I have to do something like `newArray[0]['cphNumber']` But I am getting an error. Can you please help me to solve this .

Comment: Could you clarify your issue a bit? I.e. provide input and desired output. For now `newArray = {}` - is a dictionary, not a list. You need to have `newArray = []` and then do `newArray.append({'cphNumber': ...., ...})`

Comment: can you try this `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")`

Comment: @aikikode Thanks man, I have read that tutorial but forgot while implementing that. Thanks again